# How do I check if a series of numbers multiplying a number n are integers

Tags: r, seq

I want to check if a series of numbers multiplying a number n are integers. However, when I use the seq function to develop this series and multiply n, then checking if it is a integer sequence, I will find something wrong, such as the following example. Please help me to figure out this question!

```
x <- seq(from=0.001, to=0.015, by=0.001)
x
[1] 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004 0.005 0.006 0.007 0.008 0.009 0.010 0.011 0.012 0.013 0.014 0.015
n <- 1000
a = x[9]*n
a
[1] 9
a == 9
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Which language do you use? Could you add more tags?

Comment: I'd tag as a dupe, but this is probably the 1e9th time someone's asked this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Answer (score 1):

Floating math operations in R may give surprising results in R, as in your example.

Using your code, you will see that there is a very small difference between the the variable **a** and 9 (note that the exact value you see may vary):

```
a-9   # yields 1.776357e-15
```

You can deal with this by comparing the difference to a very small value:

```
abs(a-9) < 1e-10  # yields TRUE
```

You will find the **compare** library useful

```
library(compare)
compare(a,9)      # yields TRUE
```

Comment: just to point out that floating point comparisons in *any* computer language may be similarly surprising. `all.equal()` may be useful too.